# VBscript select case for combobox

Tags: vbscript, combobox, sql

He there, I'm new to VB script and I am trying to make a select case to change an emailadress to a combobox choice. I know i'm thinking to easy but i need help with the direction. the combobox works but i cannot get the value chosen in the combobox to trigger the select case.

```
  Sub Item_Open()

  Set FormPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Message")

  Set Control = FormPage.Controls("Subject")

  Control.PossibleValues = "SPOED;STATUS;MANCO;KLACHT;TRANSPORT;TRACKING;INKOMEND;REPARATIE;RETOUREN;LADEN;MILKRUN"

  Set MyPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Message")
    Set Mail = MyPage.Item("Subject").Value

    Select Case Mail
        Case SPOED   
            Item.To = "hihi@blabla.com"         

        Case STATUS
            Item.To = "haha@blabla.com"

        Case else
            Item.To = ""    

    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MyPage.Item("Subject").Value` returns a string value like "STATUS". Then you must pick it up in a **string** variable:

```
strMail = MyPage.Item("Subject").Value  ' look ma, no Set!
```

The `Select Case X` statement evaluates the `X` expression and compares it to the values Y, ... in the `Case Y` parts and executes the first block for which (the values of) X and Y are equal. To apply this to `strMail` containing strings like "SPOED", the Case Y expressions should be string literals:

```
Select Case strMail
   Case "SPOED"
     ...
   Case "STATUS"
     ...
```

If you would have used `Option Explicit`, VBScript would have told, that `SPOED` (etc) is (understood as) an unitialized variable that can't be equal to a (decent) `strMail`.